# i want to access index.php either logged in or not but with login detail on index page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am confused with session handling. I want to access my index page either user has logged in or not. But if a user is logged in, then i want to replace my login and sign up buttons with logout. If not logged in then show login and sign up menus. But in both cases index page should be accessible.
When i include session file in header then index page is only being shown to logged-in user. And if i write only session_start(); at the top of page and check

```
if(isset $_SESSION['login_user'])
{  echo $login_session
}
```

```html
//index.php
        <?php
        $currentPage = 'index';
        include_once "header.php"; ?>
     <div class="stle">
          <h1> welcome to home page</h1>
          //menus
          //slider
          // posts
          </div>
       
        <?php include_once "footer.php"; ?>
```

```html
//session.php

<?php
       include('dbconn.php');
       session_start();
       
       $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];
       
      
     /*  $ses_sql = mysqli_query($conn,"select name,email from signup_work where email = '$user_check' ");*/
        $ses_sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT name,email
        FROM signup_hire
        WHERE signup_hire.email = '$user_check'

        UNION
        SELECT name,email
        FROM signup_work
        WHERE signup_work.email = '$user_check' ");
       $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
       
        /*printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
        exit();*/

       $login_session = $row['name'];
       
       if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
          header("location:login.php");
       }
    ?>
```

```html
// header.php

    <?php session_start(); 
    $login_session=""; ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie8 no-js"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie9 no-js"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <html lang="en">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <!-- BEGIN HEAD -->



    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Job Monster </title>
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
        <!--srart theme style -->
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- end theme style -->
        <!-- favicon links -->
         <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png" />


    </head>

    <body>
        <!--Loader Start -->
        <div class="mj_preloaded">
            <div class="mj_preloader">
                <div class="lines">
                    <div class="line line-1"></div>
                    <div class="line line-2"></div>
                    <div class="line line-3"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="loading-text">LOADING</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Loader End -->
        <div class="mj_header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="mj_logo">
                            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="logo">
                            </a>
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mj_menu" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">MENU</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse mj_navmenu" id="mj_menu">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="<?php if($currentPage =='index'){echo 'active';}?>"><a href="index.php">home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Jobs</a>
                                    <ul class="sub_menu">
                                        <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="jobs_location.html">location</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="job_detail.html">Job Detail</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="<?php if($currentPage =='post_job'){echo 'active';}?>"><a href="post_job.php">Post a Job</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Post a Resume</a>
                                    <ul class="sub_menu">
                                        <li><a href="post_resume.html">Post a Resume</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="resume_preview.html">Resume Preview</a>
                                        </li>
                                        
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Candidates</a>
                                    <ul class="sub_menu">
                                        <li><a href="candidates.html">Candidates</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="candidates_detail.html">Candidate detail</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li ><a href="#">Pages</a>
                                    <ul class="sub_menu">
                                        <li><a href="blog_fullwidth.html">blog fullwidth</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="blog_sidebar.html">blog sidebar</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="blog_single.html">blog single</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="gallery.html">gallery</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a>
                                        </li>
             <li><a href="signup.php">sign up</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="login.php">login</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="error.html">error</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right mj_right_menu mj_withoutlogin_menu">
                                <li class="mj_searchbtn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                                    <div class="mj_search_option">
                                        <form>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type and Hit Enter">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                
                               <?php
                                
                             if (isset($_SESSION['login_user']))
                             { 
                             ?>
                        <!-- Details -->
                        <div style="float:right; padding-left: 60px; color:#00fd36;"> <li>Welcome<br> <?php echo $login_session; ?></li>
                                 
                                  <p><a href = "logout.php">Sign Out</a></p></div>
                           
                            
                        
                        <!-- END Details -->
                        <?php
                        }
                        else { ?>
                        <!-- Details -->
                        <li class="<?php if($currentPage =='signup'){echo 'active';}?>"><a href="signup.php"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Sign Up</a>
                                </li>
                        <li class="<?php if($currentPage =='login'){echo 'active';}?>"><a href="login.php"  data-target="#myModal2"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Login</a>
                                </li>
                        <!-- END Details -->
                        <?php } ?>
                                
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set a session if user is successfully login like:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
```

and check it like:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']))
{
    // show logout button here
}
else
{
    // show login button here
}
```

Comment: for this i have to include session.php file in header and as header is same for all files it will ask for login first

Comment: and what is logged_in

Comment: Why not just use Session_start(); ? then your sesssion is started and you can use it on the answer above.

Comment: When you validate if the user should be logged in or not you should use `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;` if the user should be logged in. This has to be one in your Login script.

Comment: @PreciousPari start the session and set any variable in session, in my case I have used "logged_in"

Comment: i am unable to understand too many suggestion can someone give me the exact code please, my files are above please make a change in them

Comment: @MayankPandeyz should i write $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true; in header , index or session file ?

Comment: Let me know where did you facing the problem?

Comment: my major problem is not setting the session problem is that how to access index page with and without logged in.

Comment: You want to make a page accessible with or without login. If login than show logout otherwise show login button ??

Comment: exactly @MayankPandeyz

Comment: Where you are not able to understand the code? Let me know so that I can explain you

Comment: Still you are stuck with the same than I will send you a proper code, please give me your email id?